# Parse error with =IF function

Tags: google-sheets

I put this in:

```
=IF(A4=2;1,(A4=4;7,A4))
```

and it keeps coming up with a parse error and I have tried to switch `;` with `,` and it still didn't work.

How do I make this work?

Comment: If you would share a spreadsheet demonstrating the problem, it would be much easier to see what's going in.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you need ?

```
=IF(A4=2;1;IF(A4=4;7;A4))
```

or, depending on your locale:

```
=IF(A4=2, 1, IF(A4=4, 7, A4))
```